# fp package documentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, fp

Where can I find more information on the `fp` package?  I have been to ctan and the author even has better documentation as a todo.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fp/

The reason I ask is because sometimes when I use `fixed point arithmetic` in some `TikZ` pictures I receive errors but other times it works just fine.  Therefore, I want to identify why it wont work in some instances.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using the `fp` package instead of the `fpu` library that ships with PGF?

Comment: @Jake I was using `fp` for accuracy when using decimals in calculations.  Is `fpu` a similar library?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's what's used by PGFPlots in the background, for example. It's documented in the PGF manual.

Comment: @Jake so `\usepackage{fpu}` or `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}` then does anything needed to be said in the tikz environment?

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}`, and then `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true} ... <your calculation> ... \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}`. The details depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is the README not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the `fp` part of the question (the TikZ part is quite different), the short answer is 'there is none'. The `fp` package has been on CTAN for many years without any changes, and the only documentation it provides is as comments in the various `.tex` files. These are terse but at least tell us what functions are available.